# Error occurred when using EF in Empty Web Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, webforms, asp.net-webpages

I am using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8.

I create a new [Empty Web Application], follow common code-first (new database) steps to use EF, which are:

1. Create a model class,
2. Create a model-context class,
3. Access some data using model-context class in a web page.

But when I run that page, I get:

Directory lookup for the file "C:\Users\XUHAI\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\EF\EmptyWeb\App_Data\EmptyWeb.WebContext.mdf" failed with the operating system error 2.

CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

While I create [Web Forms] or [MVC] project, and perform the same steps, everything goes fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Operating system error 2 is "File not found".

Make sure the directory "C:\Users\XUHAI\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\EF\EmptyWeb\App_Data" exists.

Check your connection string for errors.